# Mouse scrolling is not working in userform VBA

Tags: excel, vba, scroll, userform

I created userform which has height more then could display on the monitor. I would like to prepare my userform more "user friendly"

- Height: 612
- KeepScrollBarsVisable - 0 - fmScrollBarsNone
- ScrollBars - 2 - fmScrollBarsVerdical
- ScrollHeight: 1100 (if I increased this number, displayed space
  (height) is also more)
- ScrollTop and Left: 0
- Top: 0
- Excel 2016.

Why I can't use mouse scroll for scrolling form down and up? I can display more only if I clik on the left scroll box.
btw. This scroll box is added automatically by ScrollBars properties.

Could you support me, what is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: Unfortunately 32-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Userforms don't support natively mousewheel scroll (AFAIK)

I post the code here so the 64 bit answer is available.

---

Based on [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/83da987f-77c4-448e-bdbd-7f1077bc9faf/how-to-use-the-mousewheel-with-a-scrollbar-control?forum=exceldev)

---

Steps:

**1- Add this code behind your UserForm:**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize() 
    HookFormScroll Me 
End Sub 
 
 
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer) 
    UnhookFormScroll 
End Sub
```

---

**2-Add one of the following to a `Module` depending on [your office architecture](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-office-what-version-of-office-am-i-using-932788b8-a3ce-44bf-bb09-e334518b8b19)**

> If Office is on 32 bit:

```
Option Explicit 
 ' Based on code from Peter Thornton here:
 ' http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d584120-a929-4e7c-9ec2-9998ac639bea/mouse-scroll-in-userform-listbox-in-excel-2010?forum=isvvba
Private Type POINTAPI 
    x                               As Long 
    y                               As Long 
End Type 
Private Type MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT 
    pt                              As POINTAPI 
    hwnd                            As Long 
    wHitTestCode                    As Long 
    dwExtraInfo                     As Long 
End Type 
 
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _ 
Alias "FindWindowA" ( _ 
ByVal lpClassName As String, _ 
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long 
 
Private Declare Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" _ 
Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _ 
ByVal hwnd As Long, _ 
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long 
 
Private Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _ 
Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" ( _ 
ByVal idHook As Long, _ 
ByVal lpfn As Long, _ 
ByVal hmod As Long, _ 
ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long 
 
Private Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" ( _ 
ByVal hHook As Long, _ 
ByVal nCode As Long, _ 
ByVal wParam As Long, _ 
lParam As Any) As Long 
 
Private Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" ( _ 
ByVal hHook As Long) As Long 
 
Private Declare Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" _ 
Alias "PostMessageA" ( _ 
ByVal hwnd As Long, _ 
ByVal wMsg As Long, _ 
ByVal wParam As Long, _ 
ByVal lParam As Long) As Long 
 
Private Declare Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" ( _ 
ByVal xPoint As Long, _ 
ByVal yPoint As Long) As Long 
 
Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _ 
ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long 
 
Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL          As Long = 14 
Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL        As Long = &H20A 
Private Const HC_ACTION            As Long = 0 
Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE        As Long = (-6) 
 
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN           As Long = &H100 
Private Const WM_KEYUP             As Long = &H101 
Private Const VK_UP                As Long = &H26 
Private Const VK_DOWN              As Long = &H28 
Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN       As Long = &H201 
 
Private Const cSCROLLCHANGE        As Long = 10 
 
Private mLngMouseHook              As Long 
Private mFormHwnd                  As Long 
Private mbHook                     As Boolean 
Dim mForm                          As Object 
 
 
Sub HookFormScroll(oForm As Object) 
    Dim lngAppInst                  As Long 
    Dim hwndUnderCursor             As Long 
     
    Set mForm = oForm 
    hwndUnderCursor = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", oForm.Caption) 
    Debug.Print "Form window: " & hwndUnderCursor 
    If mFormHwnd <> hwndUnderCursor Then 
        UnhookFormScroll 
        Debug.Print "Unhook old proc" 
        mFormHwnd = hwndUnderCursor 
        lngAppInst = GetWindowLong(mFormHwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE) 
        If Not mbHook Then 
            mLngMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx( _ 
            WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf MouseProc, lngAppInst, 0) 
            mbHook = mLngMouseHook <> 0 
            If mbHook Then Debug.Print "Form hooked" 
        End If 
    End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub UnhookFormScroll() 
    If mbHook Then 
        UnhookWindowsHookEx mLngMouseHook 
        mLngMouseHook = 0 
        mFormHwnd = 0 
        mbHook = False 
    End If 
End Sub 
 
Private Function MouseProc( _ 
    ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _ 
    ByRef lParam As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT) As Long 
    On Error Goto errH 'Resume Next
    If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then 
        Debug.Print "action" 
        Debug.Print "right window" 
        If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then 
            Debug.Print "mouse scroll" 
            MouseProc = True 
            If lParam.hwnd > 0 Then 
                mForm.ScrollTop = Application.Max(0, mForm.ScrollTop - cSCROLLCHANGE) 
            Else 
                mForm.ScrollTop = Application.Min(mForm.ScrollHeight - mForm.InsideHeight, mForm.ScrollTop + cSCROLLCHANGE) 
            End If 
            Exit Function 
        End If 
    End If 
    MouseProc = CallNextHookEx( _ 
    mLngMouseHook, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam) 
    Exit Function 
errH: 
    UnhookFormScroll 
End Function
```

> If Office is on 64 bit:

```
Option Explicit
 ' Based on code from Peter Thornton here:
 ' http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7d584120-a929-4e7c-9ec2-9998ac639bea/mouse-scroll-in-userform-listbox-in-excel-2010?forum=isvvba
Private Type POINTAPI
    x                               As Long
    y                               As Long
End Type
Private Type MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
    pt                              As POINTAPI
    hwnd                            As Long
    wHitTestCode                    As Long
    dwExtraInfo                     As Long
End Type
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" _
Alias "GetWindowLongA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" _
Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" ( _
ByVal idHook As Long, _
ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, _
ByVal hmod As Long, _
ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hHook As Long, _
ByVal nCode As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, _
lParam As Any) As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal hHook As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PostMessage Lib "user32.dll" _
Alias "PostMessageA" ( _
ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal wMsg As Long, _
ByVal wParam As Long, _
ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal xPoint As Long, _
ByVal yPoint As Long) As Long
 
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32.dll" ( _
ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
 
Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL          As Long = 14
Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL        As Long = &H20A
Private Const HC_ACTION            As Long = 0
Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE        As Long = (-6)
 
Private Const WM_KEYDOWN           As Long = &H100
Private Const WM_KEYUP             As Long = &H101
Private Const VK_UP                As Long = &H26
Private Const VK_DOWN              As Long = &H28
Private Const WM_LBUTTONDOWN       As Long = &H201
 
Private Const cSCROLLCHANGE        As Long = 10
 
Private mLngMouseHook              As Long
Private mFormHwnd                  As Long
Private mbHook                     As Boolean
Dim mForm                          As Object
 
 
Sub HookFormScroll(oForm As Object)
    Dim lngAppInst                  As Long
    Dim hwndUnderCursor             As Long
     
    Set mForm = oForm
    hwndUnderCursor = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", oForm.Caption)
    Debug.Print "Form window: " & hwndUnderCursor
    If mFormHwnd <> hwndUnderCursor Then
        UnhookFormScroll
        Debug.Print "Unhook old proc"
        mFormHwnd = hwndUnderCursor
        lngAppInst = GetWindowLong(mFormHwnd, GWL_HINSTANCE)
        If Not mbHook Then
            mLngMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx( _
            WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf MouseProc, lngAppInst, 0)
            mbHook = mLngMouseHook <> 0
            If mbHook Then Debug.Print "Form hooked"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
 
Sub UnhookFormScroll()
    If mbHook Then
        UnhookWindowsHookEx mLngMouseHook
        mLngMouseHook = 0
        mFormHwnd = 0
        mbHook = False
    End If
End Sub
 
Private Function MouseProc( _
    ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByRef lParam As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT) As Long
    On Error GoTo errH 'Resume Next
    If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then
        Debug.Print "action"
        Debug.Print "right window"
        If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then
            Debug.Print "mouse scroll"
            MouseProc = True
            If lParam.hwnd > 0 Then
                mForm.ScrollTop = Application.Max(0, mForm.ScrollTop - cSCROLLCHANGE)
            Else
                mForm.ScrollTop = Application.Min(mForm.ScrollHeight - mForm.InsideHeight, mForm.ScrollTop + cSCROLLCHANGE)
            End If
            Exit Function
        End If
    End If
    MouseProc = CallNextHookEx( _
    mLngMouseHook, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
    Exit Function
errH:
    UnhookFormScroll
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately my office is 32-bit.

Comment: @PawelU The code I posted works on 32 bit version. Use it and let me know how it goes

Comment: 100% works. Thanks. Can you write me where is the value of speed my scroll? At the moment, works but very slowly.

Comment: I believe that’s a setting you control in Windows

Comment: @RicardoDiaz If I'm not mistaken, your 64-bit API declarations are not correct. Pointers and handles (e.g. hwnd) should be LongPtr, which is 64-bits in 64-bit Office on 64-bit Windows, otherwise it's 32-bits. This code might work if your application's memory footprint is small enough (and you're lucky).

Comment: @TomtheToolman not all the variables have that size in 64 bits. AFAIK their original declaration requires the long type.

Comment: @RicardoDiaz You should check out [this Microsoft download](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?familyid=035b72a5-eef9-4baf-8dbc-63fbd2dd982b). When you look at the documentation, you'll see that handles and memory addresses are all 64-bit if you are using 64-bit Office on 64-bit WIndows.

Comment: @TomtheToolman, thanks for the link. I tested the 64-bit code, and it works as is.

Comment: I am getting a compile error within the HookFormScroll sub on the 64 bit version. It is saying "invalid use of AddressOf" operator, referring to the line: 
mLngMouseHook = SetWindowsHookEx( _
            WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf MouseProc, lngAppInst, 0)

Comment: @LoganPrice Just tested it with win10_64bit/excel365_64bit current channel and it's working

Answer (score 3):

The Window of a VBA Userform (old Thunderframe) does not process any mouse messages. You can quickly test that with Spy++. However the mouse can be hooked.

Although @RicardoDiaz provided an example I should mention that his hook is global meaning that you are tracking mouse messages across al threads of all processes. Really slow and does not look smooth. Instead you could use a local hook (local thread only).

You can use the code at my repository [VBA UserForm MouseScroll](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-UserForm-MouseScroll) which works on both x32 and x64 versions. It will also scroll the form, frames, comboboxes, listboxes and so on. Supports horizontal scroll and zoom as well. Enjoy!

#### Edit #1 --- 12-Oct-2023

The linked repository now supports both Modeless and Modal forms. Debugging is also working while mouse is hooked.

Comment: I get Statement to complex error when I try to import the modules. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @DumitruDaniel Try downloading the [Zip](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-UserForm-MouseScroll/archive/refs/heads/master.zip) and then extract. The modules there should import correctly

Comment: This works quite well and smoothly. However, I have noticed that when the VBA editor is open, UserForm's _Activate events don't trigger when the mouse is hooked and when focus shifts to an external application then back again. I need to manually run DisableMouseScroll for the active UserForm before buttons will function. Mouse scroll can be re-enabled and everything works again until next time focus shifts. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @hartacus Many thanks for letting me know - this kind of feedback is very useful. I will try to investigate this towards the end of this week and will let you know. For now I opened an [issue](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-UserForm-MouseScroll/issues/34) for myself.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in Excel, The Visual Basic editor must be closed !!! Excel->error !!!

The correct code for the call

Modul 1:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ShowModal()
    UserForm1.Show vbModal
End Sub

Public Sub ShowModeless()
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
End Sub
```

Modul 2:

```
Option Explicit
Private Const WH_MOUSE_LL          As Long = 14
Private Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL        As Long = &H20A
Private Const HC_ACTION            As Long = 0
Private Const GWL_HINSTANCE        As Long = (-6)
Private Const WHEEL_DOWN           As LongPtr = 7864320
Private Const WHEEL_UP             As LongPtr = 4287102976#

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As LongPtr, ByVal hmod As LongPtr, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr, ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, lParam As Any) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As LongPtr) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByRef lpPoint As POINTAPI) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function WindowFromPoint Lib "user32" (ByVal Point As LongLong) As LongPtr                                                                '
Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindowLong Lib "user32.dll" Alias "GetWindowLongPtrA" (ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal nIndex As Long) As LongPtr

Private Type POINTAPI
    XY As LongLong
End Type

Private Type MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT
    pt As POINTAPI
    hwnd As LongPtr
    wHitTestCode As Long '????
    dwExtraInfo As LongPtr
End Type
 
Private HookPtr As LongPtr, EventControl As Object, EventPtr As LongPtr
 
'------------------
'Hook, Proc, UnHook
'------------------
 
Public Sub HookControl(NewEventControl As Object)
    If HookPtr = 0 Then
       Set EventControl = NewEventControl
       EventControl.BackColor = vbRed 'Test
       EventPtr = CurserPtr
       HookPtr = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf MouseProc, FormPtr, 0)
    End If
End Sub
 
Private Function MouseProc(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As LongPtr, ByRef lParam As MOUSEHOOKSTRUCT) As LongPtr
    On Error GoTo 1
    MouseProc = CallNextHookEx(HookPtr, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)

    Dim WheelScrool As Variant
    Select Case True
           Case EventControl Is Nothing: UnHookControl
           Case EventPtr <> CurserPtr: UnHookControl
           Case HookPtr = 0
           Case nCode <> HC_ACTION
           Case wParam <> WM_MOUSEWHEEL
           Case lParam.hwnd = WHEEL_DOWN: WheelScrool = EventControl.ListIndex - 1
           Case lParam.hwnd = WHEEL_UP:   WheelScrool = EventControl.ListIndex + 1
    End Select
    If Not IsEmpty(WheelScrool) Then
       WheelScrool = IIf(WheelScrool < 0, 0, WheelScrool)
       WheelScrool = IIf(WheelScrool > EventControl.ListCount - 1, EventControl.ListCount - 1, WheelScrool)
       If EventControl.BackColor <> vbYellow Then EventControl.BackColor = vbYellow 'Test
       EventControl.ListIndex = WheelScrool
    End If
    Exit Function

1:  UnHookControl
End Function

Public Sub UnHookControl()
    If HookPtr <> 0 Then
       UnhookWindowsHookEx HookPtr
       HookPtr = 0
       EventControl.BackColor = vbGreen 'Test
       Set EventControl = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

'---------------------------
'Status query (not required)
'---------------------------

Public Property Get IsHookControl() As Boolean
    IsHookControl = (HookPtr <> 0)
End Property

'------------------
'Pointer Functionen
'------------------

Public Function CurserPtr() As LongPtr
    Dim tPT As POINTAPI: GetCursorPos tPT
    CurserPtr = WindowFromPoint(tPT.XY)
End Function

Private Function FormPtr() As LongPtr
    Dim fHw As LongPtr: fHw = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", EventControl.Parent.Caption)
    FormPtr = GetWindowLong(fHw, GWL_HINSTANCE)
End Function
```

Userform:

```
'-----------------------------
'Elemente:
'   ComboBox1
'   ListBox1
'   ListBox2
'-----------------------------

Option Explicit

Private ActControl As Object

'---------
'User Form
'---------

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 10 To 30
        ListBox1.AddItem i & " - ListBox1"
        ListBox2.AddItem i & " - ListBox2"
        ComboBox1.AddItem i & " - ComboBox1"
    Next
    ComboBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    UnHookControl
End Sub

'----------------------------
'CombBox1, ListBox1, ListBox2
'----------------------------

Private Sub ComboBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    HookControl ComboBox1
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    HookControl ListBox1
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    HookControl ListBox2
End Sub
```